# Ordering tests in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to order tests without using Test Manager?
I need ordered running, not ordered displaying.
Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need the tests to run in a certain order?  That implies to me that the tests are externally dependent on other factors and have side-effects, which could arguably invalidate what's being tested.  Each test should be isolated and discrete and should not affect state outside of the test.

Comment: It takes more actions, when tests are discrete. And more time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Ordered Test item.  It's a test type that contains other tests and will execute them in the order you specify:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286704(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631(v=vs.110).aspx

Best,
Chris